# sorting single criteria alphabetically in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list called `lsNearCities`:

```
def calcDistance(self):
    try:
        for lyr in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
            if lyr.name() == "us_cities":
                layer = lyr
                lsNearCities = []
                filePath = self.dlg.fileNameEdit.text()
                if len(str(filePath)) ==0:
                    QMessageBox.warning(self.dlg, "File Name","Give it a file name and try again")        
                    return

                if self.dlg.DistancelineEdit.text():
                    dist = float(self.dlg.DistancelineEdit.text())*(1609.344)
                    if dist != 0:
                        centerCity = self.dlg.Citycombo.currentText()
                        if dist and centerCity:
                            ct = self.dlg.Statecombo.currentText()
                            exp = QgsExpression("\"state\"='" + ct + "' AND \"name\"='"+ centerCity +"'" )
                            try:
                                it = layer.getFeatures( QgsFeatureRequest( exp ) )
                                for feature in it:
                                    #QMessageBox.information(self.dlg, "Feature selected", str(feature['state']) + str(feature['name']) + " was selected")
                                    mbuf = feature.geometry().buffer(dist,2)       
                                    iterFeat = layer.getFeatures()
                                    for f in iterFeat:
                                        geom2 = f.geometry()
                                        valTest = QgsGeometry.within(geom2, mbuf)
                                        if valTest:
                                            idx = layer.fieldNameIndex('name')  #name of the attribute column with the cities in it
                                            idx1 = layer.fieldNameIndex('state')
                                            nearCity = f.attributes()[idx]
                                            state = f.attributes()[idx1]
                                            state_and_cities = str(nearCity)  + "," + str(state)
                                            lsNearCities.append(state_and_cities)
                                            sorted(lsNearCities, key=operator.itemgetter(1,0))
```

Is there any possibility of sorting state alone alphabetically from the list using python?

Comment: Yes, of course there is a way to sort this list on the `state` part of each entry. Show us the way you have tried.

Comment: A string is just an array of char-s, so you just need to use the 0 position of each string and sort it accordingly. In your case just loop across the string untill you find a ',' and use the next char.

Comment: Can you show us part of the list `lsNearCities`? Can you explain what the code you have inserted does and why it is present?

Comment: lsNearCities is a list that is based and dependent on the users selection.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the city and state names don't have commas in them, you can use [split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
lsNearCities.sort(key=lambda x: x.split(',')[1])
```